# Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm getting a warning like Unconditional layout inflation which is causing the layout to exit and app goes crashing.I need to inflate this layout without crashing. 
the crashing is on the following code.
I have the code for the custom adapter set.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Response.NodesEntity> mMovieitem;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context mContext, List<Response.NodesEntity> mMovieitem) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mMovieitem = mMovieitem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mMovieitem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mMovieitem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.s, parent, false);

    Response.NodesEntity item = (Response.NodesEntity) getItem(position);

    ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.video_url);

    String imageUrl = item.getVideoTumbnail().getSrc();
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).into(thumbnail);
    title.setText(item.getTitle());
    rating.setText(item.getHlsVideo());

    return rowView;
}
```

}

The Xml is in this format . I'm inflating this layout and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/video_list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FriendsFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_material_light"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/video_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should properly use the convertView and not always inflate the layout. There's tons of tutorials on that

Answer (score 0):

use View holder method for inflating each rows

Comment: Could you please elaborate? did you mean ViewHolder?

Comment: there are many tutorials regarding the view holder techniques, its like re using inflated rows again